# isql error could not sqlExecute on listagg

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, isql

I'm attempting to do a LISTAGG in iSQL connecting to an oracle DB.

The following query runs fine and returns 106 results.

```
SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM dba_segments WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'EXFSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'SQLTXPLAIN', 'XDB', 'WMSYS', 'PERFSTAT', 'OUTLN');
```

Trying to then LISTAGG I get the following error:

Method 1:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(DISTINCT owner, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY owner) FROM dba_segments WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'EXFSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'SQLTXPLAIN', 'XDB', 'WMSYS', 'PERFSTAT', 'OUTLN');
```

returns:

```
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLExecute
```

Method 2:

```
SELECT LISTAGG(owner, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY owner) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM dba_segments WHERE owner NOT IN ('SYS', 'SYSTEM', 'EXFSYS', 'DBSNMP', 'SQLTXPLAIN', 'XDB', 'WMSYS', 'PERFSTAT', 'OUTLN'));
```

returns:

```
LISTAGG(OWNER,',')WITHINGROUP(ORDERBYOWNER)
```

Do functions like `LISTAGG` even work from iSQL utilizing an ODBC connection to Oracle.

edit - I found the following looks like it's not allowed?  [Allowed Functions](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ODBCU/apb.htm#ODBCU725)

```
Oracle Database Gateway for ODBC assumes that ODBC driver provider that is being used supports the following minimum set of SQL functions:

AVG(exp)
LIKE(exp)
COUNT(*)
MAX(exp)
MIN(exp)
NOT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comments in the quesiton isql cannot access system functions in Oracle.